# Sort a List while sending the parameter to a function in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I create a list(document-fragment of xml) based on the certain conditions and i wanted to sort based on the one of the attribute in the list ?
How can i achieve this

this is the call template

```
<xsl:call-template name="tempDiagnosisByNomenId">
    <xsl:with-param name="dxNomenId" select="$nomenId"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="dxList" select="key('keyDxByNomenId', $nomenId, $root-node)[@is-active='true']"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="hasDxOrders" select="$hasDxOrders"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

i want to sort the parameter dxList based on attribute then send to the function.

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use (XSLT 3 based on XPath 3 has a `sort` function, XSLT 2/3 have `xsl:perform-sort`)? Where do you use a function in there? You seem to be calling a named template, not to be calling a function?

Comment: I use XSLT 2.0 .... Yes named template am calling

Comment: I want to sort the list dxList based on clinical-priority then send to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to ask questions without seeing the XML input but if you change

```
<xsl:with-param name="dxList" select="key('keyDxByNomenId', $nomenId, $root-node)[@is-active='true']"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:with-param name="dxList" as="node()*">
  <xsl:perform-sort select="key('keyDxByNomenId', $nomenId, $root-node)[@is-active='true']">
    <xsl:sort select="@some-attribute"/>
  </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:with-param>
```

then the nodes returned by the `key` function call should be passed as the parameter `dxList` sorted on the `some-attribute` attribute instead of being in the normal document order the `key` function call returns. See the spec on `perform-sort` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-perform-sort.

As an alternative you could define a function with `xsl:function` that has the one input parameter and uses the `xsl:perform-sort` in the function body, then you could keep the `xsl:with-param` more compact by calling that function in the `select` expression.

And in XSLT 3 with higher-order function support you could use the `sort` function instead directly with e.g.

```
<xsl:with-param name="dxList" select="sort(key('keyDxByNomenId', $nomenId, $root-node)[@is-active='true'], (), function($node) { $node/@some-attribute })"/>
```